# Rewrite image url in the RSS feed using Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, pipe, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to display full-sized images in Pinterest RSS feed instead of thumbnails using this Yahoo Pipe:
`http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4cc22a300ac57e4a88f908f0548ff79e`

In order to display large images I need to rewrite image URL for every item and change last symbol before the extension from "b" to "c" in example:

in original Pinterest RSS: `http://pinterest.com/chalkboardnails/feed.rss`

change from 
`http://media-cache-ec6.pinterest.com/upload/90916486199089541_BOwL6p5P_b.jpg` 
to
`http://media-cache-ec6.pinterest.com/upload/90916486199089541_BOwL6p5P_c.jpg`

How could I do this.
Thank you

Comment: Did you take a look @ http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=string and trying to do a find and replace

Answer (score 1):

to find `b` try `(?<=http://.*/[A-Za-z\d]*_[A-Za-z\d]*_)(.*?)(?=\.jpg)`

Answer (score 1):

Use the REGEX function in Yahoo Pipes : [image: as follows]

Lee